# Adding bootstrap in bundleconfig doesn't work in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I met an issue, strange in my point of view.

I installed bootstrap via nuget package console.

After that, in `BundleConfig.cs` file, I added two items to `bundles` list:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"));

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/bootstrap").Include(
                     "~/Content/bootstrap.min.css", 
                     "~/Content/bootstrap-theme.min.css"));
```

Of course, these files exist locally.

The `_Layout.cshtml` file contains

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrap")

</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

But when I see a view (for example login page), I see that bundle doesn't append bootstrap part.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Login</title>
    <link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>    
    <!-- I expect bootstrap here but it is not displayed -->
</head>
<body>

...

<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<!-- I expect bootstrap here but it is not displayed -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

When using Bundle, do not append the `.min`

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/bootstrap").Include(
    "~/Content/bootstrap.css", 
    "~/Content/bootstrap-theme.css"));
```

Based on the debug setting, (mostly web.config)

- `debug="true"` - the non minified version will be used.
- `debug="false"` - `*.min.css` will be searched, and if not found, the current will be minified

web.config setting:

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true"...
```

Comment: You saved my new year :). That `.min.` affects my brain :)) Thanks.

Comment: It is a nice feature.  But what I find annoying is that if you dont know this you are scratching your head.  Also, you need to download both unless you you put debug to true

Comment: Important: When you are debugging it needs the non-min file.  If it doesn't exist then it won't be included.