# Bootstrap - collapsed menu won't open

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using boostrap and my collapsed menu won't open.  I've include the jquery and bootstrap js files to no avail.  My site is http://joseph-anthony-king.com/.  The code is as follows:

```
    <div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button"
                        class="navbar-toggle"
                        data-toggle="collapse"
                        data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a id="siteTitle" class="navbar-brand" href="/">Joseph Anthony King</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="/">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="/Resume">Resume</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="/Downloads">Downloads</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="https://joe-king-sample-app.herokuapp.com/" target="_blank">
                        Sample App
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `data-target` in your `button-tag` is wrong it shouldn't be the class, it should be an `id` of the collapsing `div`. So What I did is give your `collapsing div` and `id` and in the `data-target` for the button, I wrote the `collapsing div id`

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myCollapseGuy"></button> 
<!--keep in mind that the collapsing div's id="myCollapseGuy" not "#myCollapseGuy"-->
```

[Bootply link here](http://www.bootply.com/w87c3RdmDQ)

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button"
                        class="navbar-toggle"
                        data-toggle="collapse"
                        data-target="#myCollapseGuy">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a id="siteTitle" class="navbar-brand" href="/">Joseph Anthony King</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="myCollapseGuy">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="/">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="/Resume">Resume</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="/Downloads">Downloads</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="https://joe-king-sample-app.herokuapp.com/" target="_blank">
                        Sample App
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I changed the id to #collapseMenu and added this id to the div, menu still is not opening.

Comment: see the bootply link. and did you change data-target to data-target="#collapseMenu "

Comment: the data-target="#collapseMenu" and the id="collapseMenu". Part of my problem is I work as a claims adjuster and they have us on an old version of ie. I'm trying bootply on my phone.

Comment: The resolution won't work on my phone either, I'll have to wait till I can get home and try the code on bootply.

Comment: the problem is probably from your javascript files. you have errors on your website when i check them on the console

Comment: I wrote this website using VS2013 and added bootstrap via NuGet. I have the following js files in my scripts folder: _reference.js, boostrap.js, boostrap.min.js, html5shiv.js, jquery-1.9.1.js, jquery-1.9.1.min.js, jquery-1.9.1.min.map, jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js, jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js,, jquery-ui.1.8.24.js, jquery-ui.1.8.24.min.js, jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js, jquery.unobstrusive-ajax.min.js, jquery.validate.js, jquery.validate.min.js, jquery.validate.unobstrusive.js, jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js., knockout-2.2.0.debug.js, knockout-2.2.0.js, modernizr-2.6.2.js, npm.js

Comment: The problem may be in how VS2013 compiles the solution.  I noted the following entry on Stack Overflow and will try this when I get home: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20869907/adding-bootstrap-in-bundleconfig-doesnt-work-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Thanks for your help, you pointed me in the right direction.  I had to render the js files.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, I had to render the jQuery and bootstrap js libraries as follows:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/bootstrap.js")
```