# can't get bootstrap to work in MVC4

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I have no idea why i can't get bootstrap to work in my MVC site. I am using VS2012, C#, MVC. If i reference bootstrap like this

```
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>

     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   
</head>
```

Bootstrap Works.

But If I download the files and reference them like this it wont:

```
<head>
     <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrapcss")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrapjs")
</head>
```

My `BundleConfig` looks like:

```
 public class BundleConfig
{       
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrapjs").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/bootstrapcss").Include(
                    "~/Content/bootstrap.min.css",
                    "~/Content/bootstrap-responsive.min.css"));         
    }
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

[Solution]

the solution in mmcrae coment worked for me. i cant up vote sry. 
i used

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/bootstrap").Include( "~/Content/bootstrap.css", "~/Content/bootstrap-theme.css"));
```

insted of

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/bootstrapcss").Include( "~/Content/bootstrap.min.css", "~/Content/bootstrap-responsive.min.css"));
```

Comment: Do the files actually live in `~/Content/` and `~/Scripts/` ? Good place to start would be to try to render the `~/Content/bootstrap.min.css` in your razor, and see if that works

Comment: Do the rendered js and css file links actually work?

Comment: I think the error is here @Styles.Render("~/BUNDLES/bootstrapcss")

Comment: @GermanoPlebani where does it say that?? There aren't any previous edits (at the time of writing) either. I would guess the files are not in the location being specified, or don't have the right names.

Comment: In my opinion you should change Content  with bundles

Comment: Chrome does not show any error using the frist option, the links. the files are in the correct folder (just checked) the .js in the "Scripts" folder and the css in the "Content" folder and they are not in any sub folder.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20869907/adding-bootstrap-in-bundleconfig-doesnt-work-in-asp-net-mvc?rq=1 best of luck

Comment: If you put the @Scripts/Styles.Render in the same order as you do when it works, does that fix the issue?

Comment: the solution in mmcrae coment worked for me. i cant up vote sry. i used bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/bootstrap").Include(
    "~/Content/bootstrap.css", 
    "~/Content/bootstrap-theme.css")); insted of bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/bootstrapcss").Include(
                    "~/Content/bootstrap.min.css",
                    "~/Content/bootstrap-responsive.min.css"));